# Detect when opacity changes

Tags: jquery, css, opacity, detect

Is there a way in `jquery` or javascript to detect when then opacity of an element changes then launch a function to add new effects like for example if you had a page where automatic things happen like an element faded in then you wanted to launch something else when that happened. How would you do this???

It is kind of like a slide show.

Here is a demo of what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/n57Zy/

Than I want when the last elements opacity changes then start the loop again

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/08/17/ie9-opacity-and-alpha.aspx

Comment: Please can you explain because I have not got a clue with javascript

Comment: That is a long sentence.

Comment: Who's changing the opacity? Wouldn't that be you, and shouldn't you know when that is happening !

Comment: There is no cross browser/accurate way of doing this. The question is how do you make opacity change? If you are using fadeIn() method then just use its callback

Comment: There are no trigger methods and I want this so that it can be a continous loop not just once over

Comment: What do you mean by <<continous loop>>? Could you provide an example of what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of what i'm talking about, gives you the idea.

```
var delayOL = d;
var fadeLoop = (function fadeLoop(i) {
    $('.slideshow img').eq(i).delay(delayOL).fadeOut(d, function () {
        i++;
        if (i === $('.slideshow').find('img').length) i = 0;
        $('.slideshow img').eq(i).fadeIn(d, function () {
            delayOL = 0;
            setTimeout(function () {
                fadeLoop(i)
            }, g);
        });
    });
})(0);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HWMq7/3/)

Comment: I don't think you understood properly I want it so that when the opacity of an element changes I can see if it is the last one then send it back to the beginning of a loop

Comment: I don't think you understood my answer, use the callback function of fade methods, not this uggly snippet using timeout as in your jsfiddle. On last fade, recall a loop...

Comment: Please can I have a demo?

Comment: Wait is there a way to stop the automatic change at the beggining as soon as it loads

Comment: Updated answer, not sure it is what you want. If you don't want to auto trigger it onload, just remove the IIFE (anonymous autocalled function) use a classic one and call it when you want.

Comment: Would it be possible with `$.when()`

Comment: when what? $.when() would be useless here but for what would you like to use it? Animations finished?

Answer (score 3):

> This is an example, how to detect change selector value in CSS using
>   javascript.

I have solution inspired by http://darcyclarke.me/dev/watch/ using [jquery.watch.js](http://darcyclarke.me/dev/watch/jquery.watch.js)

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("div").watch('opacity', function(){
        alert("OMG!");
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/KWqUv/1/

Comment: Is there a way without a plugin?

Comment: I am trying to make a slideshow without using a plugin and that would defeat the object

Comment: You can compress this to `min` and paste to source.

Comment: as I said that would still be using a plugin

Comment: I think using like a plugin will be the best. Because it's only one function with callback. The same thing it will be...