# Play background music/audio through opacity changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skrollr

I'm making a scrolling story. All the divs are positioned on top of each other with `position: fixed` and fade in and out of each other through scrolling animations.

I need to have some music and audio play in the background when certain divs are showing so I thought the easiest way would be having some sort of `if opacity is more than 0 on div 1 play this audio`. But I don't know if that's possible through jQuery and how that would work?

The fade animation are BTW controlled with [skrollr](https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/). It's a css animation library for parralax scrolling and such.

Comment: Might be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898157/detect-when-opacity-changes

Comment: You could do that. You would either need to do the check periodically (i.e. twice a second or whatever time frame you choose) or tie it to an event, such as if the user scrolls.